# Need query in splitting the column value into three different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in a query in splitting a column value into three different columns.

This is the column which I've in my database.

```
Asset
----------------------------------------------
AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF@hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc
```

I would like to split it as below

```
Asset                             InstanceName      ServerName
---------------------------------------------------------------
AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF@hkp04lp0605s-   AP4INPU1          hkp04lp0605
rs6000.hk.hsbc
```

Initially the server name is ending with 's' but I don't want 's' at the end in the new `ServerName` column.

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  MySQL and Oracle are very different databases.  Please tag correctly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using Oracle SQL developer tool that's why I've included MySQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT Asset,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '(.+):.+@',1,1,'i',1) Instancename ,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '.+@(.+)s-',1,1,'i',1) Servername
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Kaushik Nayak, after executing your query I'm getting output like 'hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc' in the Servername but I only want 'hkp04lp0605' without 's-rs6000.hk.hsbc'.

Comment: @Vikas : Modified . check now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server name does not end in two "s"s (it looks like the preceding character is a number), you can do:

```
select regexp_substr(asset, '[^:]+', 1, 1) as instancename,
       trim(trailing 's' from trim(':' from regexp_substr(asset, ':[^-]+', 1, 1))) as servername
from (select 'AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF@hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc' as asset from dual) x
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I've thousands to records in my table but it is giving me only one records because in the code we are manually inputting 'AP4INPU1:INPRD1HF@hkp04lp0605s-rs6000.hk.hsbc'.

Comment: @Vikas . . . The `from` clause is just to demonstrate that it works.  The code you want is in the outer `select`.

Comment: thanks for that, I modified the code and is working now.